# Xampp showing cached pages when accessed from a browser in the network or VM host

Tags: xampp, ubuntu-16.04

I installed xampp-linux-x64-5.6.20 on Ubuntu 16(64 bit) VM. I am facing a strange problem.

When I make a change in my .html file and access the page from broswer locally, I can see the changes . But when I access my html page from a browser in the host Win 7 system, I see the old version of the page. I do not see the changes.

I tried setting the 'CacheDisable' directive in httpd.conf as well as .htaccess in my web app but with no success.

Is this a xampp feature or Ubuntu 16 feature.

Comment: You can do a hard refresh to load a fresh page.. Just press `Ctrl+f5` instead of just pressing `f5`

Comment: P.S. Saving .html files in the cache is a browser feature. Browsers do that to load pages faster

Comment: Thanks for Ctrl+f5. its happening with php files too. I tested clearing the browser cache  and then test. But the problem seems to be on ubuntu /xampp end. why the problem occurs only from a browser other than host system.

Comment: Installed Tomcat and tried the same test with a jsp file. When I try the jsp page with a browser from my host system, i see the changes immediately. So I do not think its a Ubuntu problem. It is a xampp /apache confi